# How to run package.json scripts programmatically in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

How do we run a custom script from package.json programmatically, for example inside a React Native component?

I know there is exec function from child_process but it says it doesn't exist. Maybe it works on the web, but how can we run it in React native? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need a server-side component, it's not possible to do this entireley from the client side.